# /usr/bin/env: RScript: No such file or directory | After recent R-3.0.1. installation.

Tags: r, path, environment-variables, rscript

I am a bit lost when dealing with installing and using R. I installed R 3.0.1 from source and did the **./configure, make, make check**, and **make install** as suggested. However I tried running R but it said that R wasn't in the /usr/bin folder. So I then copied the entire R-3.0.1/bin directory into my /usr/bin directory using **cp**. Now I'm getting a few errors regarding /usr/bin/env when trying to use RScript on a hello_world.R script I wrote from the O'Reilly R In a Nutshell book I store in a file hello_world.R the contents are below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env RScript
print("Hello World!");
```

Simple enough, but when I try to load it I get the following error:

```
$ ./hello_world.R
/usr/bin/env: RScript: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure if this is a PATH problem or something, but when I search in my /usr/bin directory I do see the RScript file in there along with (R, BATCH, and the others associated with R programming language). Any help is greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: What OS/distro are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring)

Comment: Any reason in particular you are trying to install from source as opposed to `apt-get install`?

Comment: I was trying to get Bioconductor, and according to their website the current version of Bioconductor needs R-3.0.1. From what I read using `apt-get install r-base` can only get you version 2.15.2 according to this [link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/r-base). I originally had installed R-2.15.2 using `apt-get` but then read the Bioconductor site and tried to install the new version by source.

Comment: `make install` usually installs software in `/usr/local/`, to avoid interference with software installed by the package manager: copying files after installation usually brings problems. What is your `$PATH`? What do `which R`, `which Rscript` return? Is `/usr/local/bin/Rscript` executable? Can you run `R`?

Comment: in R what is the output of `Sys.which("Rscript")` ?

Comment: I can run R. My $PATH is `echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
` Which R returns `/usr/local/bin/R` and which RScript doesn't return anything. In R the `Sys.which("Rscript")` returns `"/usr/local/bin/Rscript"`

Comment: It is `Rscript`, not `RScript`...

Comment: That was the problem, it works with the lowercase 's', there must be a typo in the book. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You may be using an invalid command line option for Rscript in your shebang line.

For instance ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env RScript --vanilla
```

remove "--vanilla" (or other offending option) and rerun your script

```
#!/usr/bin/env RScript
```

I know you didn't put this in your example, but the solution may help others searching for the same issue.

Comment: indeed the solution helped others :) me!

Answer (score 4):

Again, the good solution to this problem is very simple and clearly explained in the man page of `env`. The script should use the `env` command to invoke `Rscript` and not `Rscript` directly:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

some R code now...
```

But a script like this will read the user's `.Rprofile` among other things. When we want to have a *vanilla* R session (in order to start with a clean and controlled R), we must pass the option `--vanilla`. If you try something like

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript --vanilla

some R code now...
```

`env` will take the string `Rscript --vanilla` a the command to execute and will inevitably return the error message

```sh
/usr/bin/env: ‘Rscript --vanilla’: No such file or directory
```

In `env`'s man page, there is an option called `-S` for splitting the strings. Its role is exactly to solve the problem above and use the first string `Rscript` as the command name, and the following strings (like `--vanilla`) as options to pass to `Rscript`.

The solution is therefore:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env -S Rscript --vanilla

some R code now...
```

Answer (score 2):

Put in the shebang line of your script `#!/usr/bin/Rscript` and it should work.

As a side remark if you want to keep up-to-date with the R versions from CRAN and not relying on the native R of your Linux distro (Ubuntu) then add the following line in your apt sources:

```
deb http://my_favorite_cran_mirror/bin/linux/ubuntu raring/
```

After that you can always use the apt system to install R which -I would agree with Jake above- it should be the preferable way to install R.

*Change the my_favorite_cran_mirror with a valid CRAN mirror that is close to you.

Comment: You are Sadly Out of Luck if `Rscript` is not installed in `/usr/bin`. Which happens e.g. on MacOS 10.11 "El Capitan" for instance. A more portable solution is to use a shebang line such as `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript` because the location of `env` is way more standard among Unices. Yes, there are UNIX-like OS-es in addition to Linux... :-)

Comment: I agree, sadly there are other "Unix-like OSes" that do not even allow admins to write to /usr/bin.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/env RScript
print("Hello World!");
```

Simple enough, but when I try to load it I get the following error:

```
$ ./hello_world.R
/usr/bin/env: RScript: No such file or directory
```

Here u make mistake is that instead of RScript write Rscript.
The syntax will be

```
#! /usr/bin/env Rscript
print("Hello World!");
```

Then run it it will work (y) all the best.

```
$./hello_world.R
```

Answer (score 1):

I arrived at this question trying to understand this error message on a cluster computer where I did not have control over the R installation.

In general, when I converted `Rscript` in my makefile to `/usr/bin/Rscript` the error message no longer occurred.